# Fundamental algorithms in formal language-automata theory

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, automata

I'm willing to take a course in formal languages and automata theory , where we will explore side by side a functional programming language to implement the different algorithms we will encounter ,despite i am new to the language , i am assuming i've learned what's nessecary to move to the theoretical part , so i'm wondering what are the must-knows of FL & AT to a programmmer , that is what are the most fundamentals algorithms one necesserily have to know while studying formal languages and automata theory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're simple, but the various DFA $\leftrightarrow$ NFA $\leftrightarrow$ RE conversions are quite handy.

Also, being able to find the Parikh mapping of a semilinear language is quite useful for more advanced applications (especially when you get out of the regular languages), since it lets you answer a lot of decidable properties.

Answer (score 3):

One of the important classes of languages you will be introduced to is *regular languages*. While studying them, you will learn the fundamental [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem). This will teach you how to connect abstract mathematical concepts like equivalence classes, to specific algorithmic constructs. In terms of algorithms, this will relate to [minimization algorithms for DFAs](http://egtheory.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/minimizing-finite-state-automata/) and understanding why similar algorithms don't exist for NFAs.